# Creating Group access for a given topic using Kafka Admin API

Tags: apache-kafka

KAFKA Admin API has method called createAcls which is used create ACLs based on the ResourceType.

Using createAcls we can create Acls to

1.ALLOW READ on TOPIC "T" for User U

2.ALLOW READ on Consumer GROUP "G" for User U

**Now my question is**

Is there any way we can CREATE an Acls using ADMIN CLIENT API to aggregate the above requirements to say

ALLOW READ on TOPIC "T" for User U for any Consumer Group G?

Comment: What is the problem of using two approaches separately? If you are insisting on using one command you can use `kafka-acl.sh` in terminal.

Comment: Basically I was trying to see options in ADMIN API to control access for a User to a topic READ just based on the Topic Resource (Using Consumer Group as '*' as it could be done in the shell command.                                                                                            Also wanted to get insight into why the APIs is not supporting this where as there is a support for it in the kafka-acl.sh. Is there any specific reasons?

Comment: I did lots of searches and couldn't find any way to do it with the admin client. maybe it's a lack of feature. as I know there shouldn't be any reason for lack of this feature.